# Chef recipe does not get the attributes from a role attached to node

Tags: chef-infra

I have a node with a role `B`. This role has some attributes inside of `default_attributes` section.

```
{
  "name": "B",
  "description": "",
  "json_class": "Chef::Role",
  "default_attributes": {
     "service_name": "my_value"
   },
   "override_attributes": {
   },
   "chef_type": "role",
   "run_list": [
   ],
   "env_run_lists": { 
   }
}
```

In a recipe that I execute on that node with a role B, I want to take the value with the key `service_name` from that role B attached to that node.

Using `node.default['service_name']` nor `node['service_name']` the value is not present. How I can get that value?

Example:

In cookbook named `sample` I have a recipe named `install`, so in `install.rb` have this line:
`Chef::Log.info("my service_name is " + node.default['service_name'])` which gives me the next error:

```
172.26.67.100 ================================================================================
172.26.67.100 Recipe Compile Error in /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/sample/recipes/install.rb
172.26.67.100 ================================================================================
172.26.67.100 
172.26.67.100 TypeError
172.26.67.100 ---------
172.26.67.100 can't convert Chef::Node::VividMash to String (Chef::Node::VividMash#to_str gives Chef::Node::VividMash)

...
...
...

172.26.67.100 Running handlers:
172.26.67.100 [2015-09-04T15:58:30+02:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
172.26.67.100 Running handlers complete
172.26.67.100 [2015-09-04T15:58:30+02:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
172.26.67.100 [2015-09-04T15:58:30+02:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
172.26.67.100 Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 2.575100287 seconds
172.26.67.100 [2015-09-04T15:58:30+02:00] ERROR: can't convert Chef::Node::VividMash to String (Chef::Node::VividMash#to_str gives Chef::Node::VividMash)
172.26.67.100 [2015-09-04T15:58:30+02:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

Comment: I've updated the post by providing some logs.

Comment: `node.default` access a specific part of the node object, the defaults values for the node (i.e values populated from attributes files or recipes), never use the level to access a node object, only to set them. And then concatenation is not done with + in ruby. Use interpolation: `Chef::Log.info("my service_name is  #{node['service_name']}")`.

Comment: the value of node['service_name'] is an empty string, different that what I have in my role. I've updated the role using `knife role edit my-role`. What I've missed?

Comment: The role is correctly added to your node runlist ?  (update your question with actual code and log please)

Answer (score 0):

It was my mistake. I figured out that if you want to take `default_attributes` from a role inside a cookbook recipe, you have to run that recipe in the role run list, which I've didn't.

So, instead of running `chef-client -o recipe[sample::default]` I had to run the role itself, with `chef-client -o recipe[B]`, and put `sample` cookbook in the `run_list` of the B role.